# Orbits of conjugation map for fixed $x\in S^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Fix $x\in S^3$ as a unit quaternion. We see that the map $v\mapsto xvx^{-1}$ for $v\in \mathbb R^3=\{ai+bj+ck: a,b,c\in \mathbb R\}$ is a group action.

My question is, how can we find the orbits of this action?

I know that $S^3$ is homeomorphic to $SU(2)$, but that doesn't give me any insight. 
I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Well....the origin is an orbit. And in general, each orbit lies in a sphere of some radius, so if you analyze this on just $S^3$ rather than all of $\Bbb R^4$, you'll get the essence of the thing. Whether that's easier or not...hard to say...; in fact, because the map takes $\{v, -v\}$ to $\{u, -u\}$, where $u = xvx^{-1}$, we see that this is really an action on $\Bbb R\Bbb P ^ 3$. But again, that may or may not be a useful observation.

Comment: What do you mean by "find"? Do you mean you want an alternative description? One can give such a description using traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for "some help", so here's a little.

First, it depends on $x$.

If $x$ is $\pm 1$, then every orbit is a point.

No matter what $x$ is, every pure-real quaternion is an orbit.

If $x$ is a pure vector quaternion, then you might as well pick $x = \mathbf i$ (via a change of coordinates if necessary), at which point you can explicitly compute to see that for any quaternion $q = r + u$, where $r$ is real and $u$ is pure-vector, the $r$ part is invariant, so you need only look at what happens to $u$. For $u = \mathbf i$, you have a fixed point; for $u = \mathbf j, \mathbf k$, you get an orbit: $\{\mathbf j, -\mathbf j\}$ or $\{\mathbf k, -\mathbf k\}$. And in general, for $a\mathbf j + b\mathbf k$, you get a similar two-point orbit.

That all happens because multiplication by $i$ represents a 90-degree rotation on the sphere of unit pure-vector quaternions. For a mixed quaternion like $\cos t + \mathbf i \sin t $, you might get much more complicated orbits, I expect, but I haven't worked out the details. I suspect that Rodrigues' formula might prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it suffices to look at unit quaternions. This space has a natural bi-invariant metric making it isometric to the round 3-dimensional sphere with distinguished point $e$ corresponding to the identity element. The orbits under conjugation are metric spheres centered at $e$. With two exceptions, these spheres are isometric to a round 2-dimensional sphere. The exceptions are $e$ and it's opposite, $-e$, when the orbits are singletons.